# many to many problem django

Tags: python, django

how in django find list of post related with special many to many field?

for example

catagory have title

post have many to many relation to catagory

how find all post from category title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give title

> ```
> category = Category.objects.get(title=title)
> post_list = category.post_set.all()
> ```

return result

Answer (score 1):

From the category objects you can retrieve the related objects using the automatically created field post_set, if the post model is named Post.

This is a bit tricky to find in the documentation because it is in a dedicated section, see here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

`Post.objects.all(catagory__title="My catagory title")`?